# create a new variable within a for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, max, min

I have a dataframe *Fix* with many variables, among these, there is CURRENT_ID, which is numeric and is between 1 and a number that varies (e.g., in certain cases 12, in other 15, etc.), and also a variable called *nitem*, that represents the number of the item in my experiment. For each trial and each subject, I would like to identify the minimum and the maximum CURRENT_ID. Then I would like to create a new variable called *Remove*. In *Remove* I would like to have a value of 1 if the CURRENT_ID is the minimum or maximum for each trial and participant, and a value of 0, for all the other rows. Following is an example of the data I have and the output I would like to obtain:

```
SESSION_LABEL   TRIAL_INDEX CURRENT_ID  nitem   OUTPUT
ppt01           1           1           4       1
ppt01           1           1           4       1
ppt01           1           4           4       0
ppt01           1           2           4       0
ppt01           1           2           4       0
ppt01           1           2           4       0
ppt01           1           4           4       0
ppt01           1           5           4       0
ppt01           1           6           4       0
ppt01           1           7           4       0
ppt01           1           8           4       0
ppt01           1           10          4       0
ppt01           1           11          4       0
ppt01           1           11          4       0
ppt01           1           12          4       0
ppt01           1           13          4       0
ppt01           1           13          4       0
ppt01           1           14          4       1
ppt01           1           1           4       1
ppt01           1           1           4       1
ppt01           2           2           2       0
ppt01           2           1           2       1
ppt01           2           5           2       0
ppt01           2           3           2       0
ppt01           2           4           2       0
ppt01           2           5           2       0
ppt01           2           5           2       0
ppt01           2           5           2       0
ppt01           2           6           2       0
ppt01           2           7           2       0
ppt01           2           8           2       0
ppt01           2           10          2       0
ppt01           2           10          2       0
ppt01           2           11          2       0
ppt01           2           13          2       0
ppt01           2           13          2       0
ppt01           2           13          2       0
ppt01           2           14          2       1
ppt01           2           3           2       0
ppt01           2           2           2       0
ppt01           2           1           2       1
ppt01           2           1           2       1
ppt01           2           1           2       1
ppt01           2           5           2       0
ppt01           2           4           2       0
ppt01           2           4           2       0
ppt01           2           5           2       0
ppt01           2           7           2       0
ppt01           2           9           2       0
ppt01           2           10          2       0
ppt01           2           12          2       0
ppt01           2           10          2       0
ppt01           2           10          2       0
ppt01           2           4           2       0
ppt01           2           5           2       0
ppt01           2           4           2       0
ppt01           2           6           2       0
ppt04           2           1           8       1
ppt04           2           1           8       1
ppt04           2           2           8       0
ppt04           2           3           8       0
ppt04           2           4           8       0
ppt04           2           5           8       0
ppt04           2           6           8       0
ppt04           2           7           8       0
ppt04           2           8           8       0
ppt04           2           7           8       0
ppt04           2           6           8       0
ppt04           2           8           8       0
ppt04           2           8           8       0
ppt04           2           10          8       0
ppt04           2           9           8       0
ppt04           2           10          8       0
ppt04           2           13          8       0
ppt04           2           14          8       1
ppt04           2           14          8       1
ppt04           2           1           8       1
ppt04           3           2           10      0
ppt04           3           2           10      0
ppt04           3           2           10      0
ppt04           3           3           10      0
ppt04           3           2           10      0
ppt04           3           4           10      0
ppt04           3           5           10      0
ppt04           3           6           10      0
ppt04           3           7           10      0
ppt04           3           9           10      0
ppt04           3           11          10      0
ppt04           3           12          10      0
ppt04           3           12          10      0
ppt04           3           13          10      0
ppt04           3           14          10      1
ppt04           3           14          10      1
```

Here is my attempt.

```
 for (j in 1:nrow(Fix)){
   Fix$Remove[j] <-ifelse(by(Fix$CURRENT_ID, list(Fix$SESSION_LABEL,Fix$nitem), max), 1,
                            ifelse(by(Fix$CURRENT_ID, list(Fix$SESSION_LABEL,Fix$nitem), min), 1,0))
   }
```

Also, I am not sure if a for loop is the best day to do it.

Comment: it would be helpful if you could provide a readable example with `dput()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

your_data %>%
  group_by(SESSION_LABEL, nitem) %>% 
  mutate(Remove = ifelse(
      CURRENT_ID == min(CURRENT_ID) | CURRENT_ID == max(CURRENT_ID),
      1, 0
  ))
```

Comment: Gregor, this seems a very nice solution. However, for some reason, it does not create the new variable Remove.

Comment: You probably need to assign the result. `your_data <- {my code}` or `your_modified_data <- {my code}` depending on whether or not you want to overwrite your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with base `R`:

```
Fix <- within(Fix, {
  mx <- ave(CURRENT_ID, SESSION_LABEL, nitem, FUN=max)
  mn <- ave(CURRENT_ID, SESSION_LABEL, nitem, FUN=min)
  Remove <- ifelse(CURRENT_ID==mx | CURRENT_ID==mn, 1, 0)
})
```

But testing the result with your data gives:

```
which(Fix$Remove!=Fix$OUTPUT)
# [1] 78 79 80 82
```